# Why did the distressing spirit from God come upon Saul

Tags: spirit

1 Samuel 18: 10-11

> 10 And it happened on the next day that the distressing spirit from
>   God came upon Saul, and he prophesied inside the house. So David played
>   music with his hand as at other times; but there was a spear in Saul's
>   hand  11 And Saul cast the spear for he said for "I will pin David to
>   the wall!" But David escaped his presence twice.

Why did the distressing spirit from God come upon Saul?

Comment: Welcome! This question (or one very similar to it) has already been asked, so this one may be closed as a duplicate. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @Nathaniel No answer was accepted for that question and it was closed as opinion-based. Can this question be narrowed so that an answer can be accepted?

Comment: @anonymouswho Yes of course, that's a fine approach as well. Gerhardt, if there is a particular Christian tradition whose view you would like, you could mention that here to potentially get the question reopened.